# Why is IPv6 expressed in hexadecimal format?

Tags: ipv6, internet

Why is ipv6 hex? Is it still okay to express it in denary?

sure xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is easier to remember than AAAA AAAA AAAA AAAA AAAA AAAA ?

Comment: Yes, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx might be easier to remember, but with IPv6, you'd be talking about xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (each number represents 8 bits, and an IPv6 address is 128 bits long) - that's too long to remember.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for switching to a hex-based representation is twofold: They're long enough that using a larger character base is helpful, and in networking in general, a power-of-two base makes calculations simpler for humans since subnet masks are bitmasks.

IPv4 addresses are about at the limit of what humans can remember without active memorization techniques, and there's perhaps some value to writing IPv4 addresses in base 10. IPv6 addresses are almost entirely impossible to remember, except occasionally as chunks of prefix+subnet+role-based address, and even in the latter, hex makes concatenating the chunks easier.

Comment: Moreover it is better practice to use DNS to resolve an IP from something more common for a human to remember, a name.